# Absolute file name in linked workbooks

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have two linked workbooks, one is called Reporting and populates a simplified version of the information gathered from entries in another workbook called Calendar.

The problem I'm running into, is once a week, I have to save a snapshot of the Reporting workbook. Once the values have been entered into the Calendar book for the week, I perform a Save As on the Reporting workbook with the snapshot date, close it, and re-open Reporting and carry on with the entries for the following week.

However, my links change in the Calendar workbook from the Reporting workbook to the snapshot I last saved it as, and every week I have to manually repair the links.

**Example**

```
='C:\Users\...\SU\[SU Reporting.xlsx]job list'!$B4
```

changes to

```
='C:\Users\...\SU\snapshots\[02 aug 2014.xlsx]job list'!$B4
```

Is there a way to keep the reference to the original workbook?

Comment: Interesting question. I've been having the same problem with some of my workbooks and what I've ended up doing is find (with the new path) and replace (with the old path). Very clunky, but it's served me well so far.

Comment: It's what I have been doing so far, but my supervisor doesn't know how to do this. I need to keep it as non-excel-user-friendly as I can.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the Reporting workbook as a template.  Make the changes in Calendar, then open Reporting and save as a workbook with the appropriate name.  The template remains unchanged.

#### Edit:

Given the moving target, you may need to do something like this:
[Calendar (on Dropbox)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mg61xj7es72977t/Calendar20140805.xlsx)
[Reporting (on Dropbox)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e8as4w6fyo4digo/Reporting.xlsx)

They'll need to be saved to the same folder and open at the same time. A macro can be used to change the Calendar name.  The formula in Reporting uses relative referencing - it can be modified to get the correct Calendar address.

Comment: I tried this, and it still changes the filename in my formulas. Does it matter that in the example above, they are in different directories? For the Reporting book, it is in my main project folder - SU in this case - but I keep the snapshots in a sub.

Comment: And this happened after saving Reporting as an `*.xltx`? The contents of templates are not modified if they are used as templates.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting all turned around here. The path in the example I gave above is actually in the Calendar wb, and this is the one that changes daily so I'm not sure if it would work as a template. This system I've created is a monster, it's inefficient and was done in steps over a few weeks, so my logics are a little.. well, illogical.

Comment: Been there, done that! A different approach given you're working with a moving target: Reporting is a macro-enabled template. The macro prompts for a Calendar name and places that name in a cell.  All Calendar-dependent formulas use that reference cell to determine the Calendar to fetch from.